# Playing a local video using AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avplayer

I just wasted like 3 hours on this and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to play a video I have stored locally using AVPlayer. This is how I launch the player:

```
- (void)openVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL {

    NSLog(@"Playing video with the url:\n%@", videoURL);
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

    AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [AVPlayerViewController new];
    playerViewController.player = player;
    [self presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

And this is the `NSURL` I'm passing:

```
+ (NSURL *)getURL:(NSString *)itemKey withType:(NSString *)itemType {

    NSString *docsDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataFilePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", itemKey, itemType]]];

    NSURL *itemURL;
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: dataFilePath]){  // if data exists
        itemURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:dataFilePath];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"The data requested does not exist! Returning an empty url file...");
        itemURL = nil;
    }
    return itemURL;

}
```

When I run `openVideo`, the output I get is:

```
Playing video with the url:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/72C35DC4-9EF1-4924-91F4-EDA4BDB6AAD3/Documents/sample.vid
```

But I keep getting a disabled video player..

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the local file you're trying to play really named `sample.vid` or did you just rename it for the code you dropped into this question?  I think AVPlayer might use the extension (e.g. `mov`, `mp4`, etc.) to determine the encoding of the video.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The file is renamed here, but it does end with `vid`. I tried renaming it to `mp4`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Don't give it the extension `.vid`.  Are you sure it is a `.mp4` file?  Can you open that file using QuickTime player on your Mac and/or mobile Safari on your device?

Comment: Yes, the file is okay (I tried with a bunch of other files too, same problem). I'll try removing the extension altogether, but why would the AVPlayer get the file's encoding from the `NSURL` anyway?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Tried changing the extension and removing it all together, but still nothing. Trying with an online video's URL works, so it has to be the local file's URL that's causing the problem.

Comment: You might want to check AVPlayerViewController.player.status and .error for a possible answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured the issue out. I was downloading my files and storing them as `NSData`, and had to use `writeToFile` and specify the correct extension to read them correctly.

```
NSString *saveFilePath; = [NSTemporaryDirectory()stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.mp4"];

[fileData writeToFile:saveFilePath atomically:YES];
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveFilePath];
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:filepath];
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there.